# Side effect of paging modus in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-artemis

we are currently experiencing that after some addresses/queues finished being paged, our application does not get any messages anymore.  It is like as if the messages are gone.  We are expecting that paging modus should not cause the disfunctionality of the cluster.  Our configuration of address-settings looks as follow:

```
        <address-settings>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq#">
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
                <config-delete-addresses>FORCE</config-delete-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="MyQueueEins">
                <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                <max-size-bytes>100Mb</max-size-bytes>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="MyQueueZwei">
                <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                <max-size-bytes>50Mb</max-size-bytes>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="MyQueueDrei">
                <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                <max-size-bytes>1Mb</max-size-bytes>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="Onlinequeue.#">
                <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                <max-size-bytes>50Mb</max-size-bytes>
            </address-setting>


            <!--default for catch all-->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10000000</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>false</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>false</auto-create-jms-topics>
                <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
                <config-delete-addresses>FORCE</config-delete-addresses>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
```

1. Are we missing something in broker.xml configuration?
2. What could be the cause why the messages are gone/ not being consumed after paging modus?

An address experiencing this issue is BoxDeliveryQueue.  In broker.xml, this queue would have the default address-setting with # as match-regex.  We are experiencing, that after paging mode on this address, the messages are not being consumed anymore.  Today I found the file system we are using to store the paged messages:

```
<paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>
```

I will check in the file system, whether messages exist in the defined directory for addresses.  If that is the case, it would mean that the system is unable to consume the messages from the file system as stated in the documentation:

```
The system will navigate on the files as needed, and it will remove the page file as soon as all the messages are acknowledged up to that point.
```

Could it be the case, that somehow because of our configuration in broker.xml the messages directly get acknowledged after being paged, so that the are not being consumed anymore?

BoxDeliveryQueue is created also in broker.xml:

```
         </address>
            <address name="BoxDeliveryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="BoxDeliveryQueue">
                  <durable>true</durable>
               </queue>
            </anycast>
         </address>
```

The consumer is a Message-Driven-Bean, pointing to the BoxDeliveryQueue

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "BoxDeliveryQueue", name = "BoxDeliveryMessageBean", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "BoxDeliveryQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "BoxDeliveryQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "rebalanceConnections", propertyValue = "true"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "resourceAdapterJndiName", propertyValue = "delivery_ra") })
public class BoxDeliveryMessageBean implements MessageListener {
```

This is so wierd.  The messages are unable to be consumed from the MDB only after the address finsihed being paged.  If the address not being paged, everything is fine.  Regarding protocols, it is configured like this:

```
        <acceptors>
            <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
            <acceptor name="artemis"
                >tcp://localhost:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;nioRemotingThreads=24</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
```

Our JavaEE-Server is Weblogic 12c.  I havent checked the thread-dumps regarding stuckthread.  I assumed that it is the issue in my configuration of Artemis-System, as I assume that the MDBs are unaware whether the message directly from memory or from paged storage.  I will check if there are stuck threads in application server.

Thank you,

Hadi

Comment: What do you mean by, "disfunctionality of the cluster"? What does clustering have to do with this issue?

Comment: It's worth noting that the `address-setting` `match` is *not* a regex. The [wildcard syntax](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html) is specific to ActiveMQ Artemis and described in the documentation.

Comment: What is the message-count, consumer-count, and delivering-count of `BoxDeliveryQueue` when this happens? You can find these details in the ActiveMQ Artemis web console.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Any update here?  There's still a few questions that are still unanswered.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.  I am still analyzing it.  We use ActiveMQ Artemis 2.13.0-redhat00006

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? It would certainly be worth upgrading at this point. Version 2.17.0 is currently the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/).

Comment: For anyone having the same (or a similar) problem: We have this issue as well, but with artemis `2.26.0`, `2.27.0` and `2.27.1`. We have raised an [issue against artemis](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4095). Feel free to upvote.

Comment: @JustinBertram In our setup message count: 15493 (but can be anything, the lowest seen has been something like 1000), consumer count: 1, delivering-count 0.